# How can I replace laptop SSD without reinstalling OS?

Tags: ssd, dell-xps

I bought a Dell XPS 13 9370 last year with only 128GB of SSD. I want to replace it with a larger one. However, is it possible for me to replace the SSD without going through the process of reinstalling Windows and other software I already have?

P.S. What is the theoretical maximum of the size of SSD I can use? Could I put in a 4GB SSD, for example?

Comment: Is this the new math:  4 GB > 128 GB?

Comment: There is no size limit, its just a mass storage device. Clone the old SSD to the new SSD, then swap them out......https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-guide/disk-clone.html

Comment: I mean 4TB, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved Windows to an SSD from a HDD a while back and the easiest way to do it is by cloning the drive which has your OS (the process is the same for SSD to SSD). The best thing about this is that you don't lose any data and don't have to waste time reinstalling the new OS.

Try using [EaseUS Partition Manager](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/)

When you clone the OS set the target as the new SSD and let the software do it's thing. After that go into the BIOS and check the boot manager to see if your new SSD is listed.If it is try booting from it and if you face no issues then you can safely delete the OS partition on the old SSD(if you wish).

Check [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Storage-at-Microsoft/Windows-10-and-reserved-storage/ba-p/428327) regarding the amount of space Windows reserves for updates.

[This article](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Question-about-upgrading-SSD-in-9370/td-p/6072439) deals with the process of installing a larger SSD for your laptop model (includes migrating OS into larger SSD).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, an easy way to do it would be to connect both ssd at the same time (the new one can be connected through a usb adapter if your laptop does not have two slots). There are various softwares that can transfer the data (that makes the destination ssd bootable) but I've found this one to be the easyest to use:

https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi.static/Samsung_SSD_Data_Migration_User_Manual_(ENG)_v.3.1.pdf

It's free but require the new ssd to be from samsung though (I would choose a samsung ssd anyway because IMHO they are great and cost almost like the others).

Obviously the new ssd must be bigger then the old one. I'm not sure about the maximum supported size, you can read about it here: https://www.minitool.com/partition-disk/win-10-max-drive-size.html anyway ssd have a good GB/price ratio up to 1TB, I don't think it makes sense to go higher unless you have the specific need to do so (1TB is almost surely supported).